# Method "setOnClickListener" is not working for button in pop up dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, button

I am making a TODO app for Androids.I got a listView and an SimpleAdapter for this, then the floatingActionButton which is used to show the pop up dialog where the user can write his TODO item and then he has to click the button in this dialog to create checkbox in listview (todo Item).So and the button which supposed to create a todo item is not working.

Appreciate your help.

There is my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var listView: ListView
    private lateinit var actionBtn: FloatingActionButton
    private lateinit var createBtn: Button
    private lateinit var etDialog: EditText

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val inflater = layoutInflater
        val dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_create, null)

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
        actionBtn = findViewById(R.id.actionBtn)
        createBtn = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.createBtn)
        etDialog = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.edTxtDialog)

        val list=ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>()
        val from = arrayOf("todoItem")
        val to = intArrayOf(R.id.listItem)

        val dialog = Dialog(this)

        val simpleAdapter = SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.list_item, from, to)
        listView.adapter = simpleAdapter

        actionBtn.setOnClickListener{
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_create)
            dialog.show()
        }
        createBtn.setOnClickListener{
            val todoItem = etDialog.text.toString()

            if(etDialog.text.isNotEmpty()){
                val map = HashMap<String,String>()
                map["todoItem"] = todoItem
                list.add(map)
                simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I guess, the problem is in

val dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_create, null)

Comment: Are you seeing your buttons and other UI elements being populated?

Comment: Btw, you should probably be using `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`

Comment: You're inflating `R.layout.dialog_create` twice. Once with `inflater.inflate()` and once with `dialog.setContentView()`. This is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rearranged your code slightly. This code inflates the dialog layout when the button is clicked, not before. It's difficult to know if this is what you want, because you didn't post any layout files or screenshots of the app.

```kotlin
val list = ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>()
val from = arrayOf("todoItem")
val to = intArrayOf(R.id.listItem)

val simpleAdapter = SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.list_item, from, to)
val listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
listView.adapter = simpleAdapter

val actionBtn = findViewById(R.id.actionBtn)
actionBtn.setOnClickListener {
    val dialogLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_create, null)
    val createBtn = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.createBtn)
    val etDialog = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.edTxtDialog)

    val dialog = Dialog(this)

    createBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val todoItem = etDialog.text.toString()

        if(etDialog.text.isNotEmpty()) {
            val map = HashMap<String,String>()
            map["todoItem"] = todoItem
            list.add(map)
            simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }

    dialog.setContentView(dialogLayout)
    dialog.show()
}
```